# Game With Space Battles

Tags: identify-this-game

This was a 4 player game ( I think tops ). Each player had their homeworld in their own galaxy separated in different sections on the board. You could attach boosters and rockets on your ships to make them more powerful. There were scouter ships and big battle ships because each ship could hold many cannons or no cannons at all in some cases. One of the ways to win was to destroy everybody but there was 1 more way to win that I cannot remember, I think it was to boost to the middle of the board.

There was also crystals on planets in your galaxy and each planet was connected with a blueish line between them you could travel. Playing certain cards would create additional paths that were permanent. You could also set up defending turrets on bases you've explored and captured. I remember you could require resources from worlds and things would end up in your scrapyard which was your own player board.

I believe there was battle with NPCs to capture small planets in a territory and all battles were a combination of dice rolling and card play.

The main board came in a few pieces but it was in a circularish with a center piece that may have been empty / space in the center. I'm not sure when this came out or what the title could have been. The board was a very unique piece of it I think.

I'm fairly certain it was not Star Wars, Star Trek, or Battlestar Galactica.

Comment: Was this a fixed board, or was the galaxy dynamically generated? Also, even if you can't guess when it would've come out, you could probably narrow that a bit by letting us know when-ish you remember *playing* it.

Comment: This is similar to *4000AD* but that didn't have defined blue paths and no dice.

Comment: I played it earlier this year - it had a bunch of little pieces for the boosters and cannons. I want to say the ships were fitted cardboard not minis but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My memory was a tad off but the game has been identified as:

[**StelCon: Infinity** (2013)](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/121813/stelcon-infinity)

[image]

Comment: Well now I'm curious as to where you played this. There were (from a conversation I had with the publisher) relatively few of these manufactured!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 My memory is fuzzy but the guy who brought it in ( was at a meetup ) said he kickstarted it and just got it in. I remember the whole game we were going through the book referencing the rules to make sure we were doing everything right.

Comment: Also, after owning this game I'm not sure I would recommend it. The cardboard bits are a bit fiddly and won't last through multiple playthrough unfortunately. That being said, I enjoy the mechanics and wouldn't mind a 2nd printing with better components. One may even be able to 3D print better components and salvage this edition.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you mean Exodus Proxima Centauri? https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/122842/exodus-proxima-centauri

I never played this game but I once saw it at a fair.

Comment: This may very well be it but I don't remember the [player sheets](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/1651113/exodus-proxima-centauri) being this big and have this many colored resources. This is closer than the previous answer.

Comment: Maybe it was another (newer/older) version or an expansion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about "Eclipse" :
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/72125/eclipse

It got some elements you described:
You can win by destroying the others or after X rounds with victory points.
War, diplomacy... with other players.
Conquer some planets to boost your industry, research, credits...
And the "ancients", an old race "NPC" to destroy to obtain powerful artefacts.
It can be played with 4 players.
You can attach weapons, shields to your ships.

But crystals on planets, blueish line to travel and "playing cards" doesn't match.

Comment: In regards to the lines, in Eclipse there are only certain paths between tiles (based on marks on the edge), and there is a tech that lets you ignore that.

Comment: This might be it but I feel like the player board was split into 3 sections, useable resources, scrapyard, and one in the middle that I cant remember. The playing cards was a big piece since they were attack modifiers and such.